# cannot show listView on fragment

Tags: android

I have a xml Layout file (**ListLayout.xml**) where i create listView and i want this layout to be shown on a fragment on main_activity_layout. so go to **MainActivity_layout** and i added a fragment , when it is proposed to choose a class i choosed the class **Listfrg** where i return the layout of listLayout.xml within OnCreateView methode , but nothing is shown why ?

**ListLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivityLayout**

```html
  <fragment
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.pack2.t9ahbin.Listfrg"
        android:id="@+id/fragment3" />
```

**Class Listfrg :**

```
public class Listfrg extends ListFragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frglist, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Is it ListLayout.xml or frglist.xml?  You are inflating frglist.xml.

Comment: it is just question of names i inflated the right one, but i cannot see the layout on the fragment

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You're not setting an Adapter on the `ListView`, so it's empty, the `TextView` has no text, so it's pretty much invisible, and the `LinearLayout` holding the `ProgressBar` is `"gone"`, so it doesn't show at all.

Comment: how to set the adapter to show just listview.

Comment: you can go through this url to know how to set adapter to list view
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: You need an adapter to hold the data. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

> nothing is shown why?

Because there is no data in your list.

Please use an ArrayAdapter or some Adapter variant, put some data into it with `adapter.add`, and the use `listView.setAdapter`. To actually give data to your Listview.

You can do this in `onCreateView` and use `getListView()` or this to get the ListView.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

An Adapter is the data container for a ListView. Without one, how do you expect to display data?

Also your empty view needs to use `android:id="@android:id/empty"`

---

This is all well covered in [AdapterViews](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)